Why can't I immerse the unit interval $[0, 1]$ in the 1-torus $T^1$?
I'm supposed to prove that I can't smoothly immerse a compact, simply connected and smooth 1-manifold into $S^1 = T^1$, the 1-torus. I don't understand why I can't do this: take my simply connected 1-manifold to be the interval $[0, 1]$. Choose an arbitrary interval, say $[0, 3 \pi/2]$ on the upper hemisphere and  immerse $[0, 1]$ into it.
There are obvious cases involving say, projections, where the differential won't have full rank, but I don't get why I can't just get an immersion on some part of the upper hemisphere.
Is there some nuance to the boundary that makes the manifold not immerse properly? I've re-read through Lee's material, found nothing on immersions in Hatcher, and briefly looked at Hirsch, Pollack, and Dundas, but I can't personally find anything that helps me write the proof. It's the same definition of the immersion with no proofs or theorems that I find easy to apply here.
I'm going a bit insane since I can't find anything to help. I assume there's something subtle about the definition that I'm not grasping, but I can't put a finger on what fails. Please give a direct answer or comment; I'm having trouble grasping the subtlety of the immersion definition clearly, so I don't want some equally subtle hint. I badly need to understand whatever part of the differential's definition I'm missing here, because I need to understand this particular model problem in order to write a larger proof of a bigger theorem.

May it be that you've actually told to prove the immersion in the other direction doesn't exist?

@lisyarus  The actual full proof I need to write is this:  Let $M$ be a compact, simply connected manifold of dimension $n$. Prove that there is no smooth immersion $f: M \rightarrow T^n$, where $T^n  = S^1 \times \cdots S^1$ is the n-torus. This is from the Stanford geom. and top. qualifying exam (publicly available, you can look it up). I'm trying to learn the material by doing as much on my own as I can. I don't want anyone to give the full proof for this theorem. I just want help figuring out what I'm not understanding from the immersion and how it works (thus the toy case in 1D)

@Nate that statement requires the assumption $M$ is boundaryless (and I would assume that this is the implicit meaning whenever the term ‘manifold’ itself is used (this is Lee’s convention, though IIRC Hirsch doesn’t adopt this), as opposed to ‘manifold-with-boundary’ (the latter term allowing for the possibility of an empty boundary)).

@peek-a-boo Were it to have boundary (like [0, 1]), could I immerse it like I asked in the problem statement? In other words, I have to prove that instead that closed manifolds of dimension $n$ can't be immersed?

$[0,1]$ can be immersed in $S^1$. Also, I’m not sure why you phrased the question like this, because it’s becoming an XY problem; ideally you should include the statement you actually want to prove, and ask whether $[0,1]$ is a counterexample to the claim (which it is not).
